# A JDBC Driver or DataSource class name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName property

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, rtc

We're working on **JSF**,**EJB**,**JPA** project. Application server is Websphere 8.0.0.8
Everything was fine until we have started using **RTC** for sharing and source control. As I understand it merged configuration files and it was impossible to compile the project. This issue we've solved by repair paths to the libraries manually. But one issue we could not repair, when we try to work with JPA project and write or read something to/from DB we get the next error.

```
[3/17/14 13:09:34:417 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R <openjpa-2.1.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1530146 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: A JDBC Driver or DataSource class name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName property.
[3/17/14 13:09:34:417 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.newDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:76)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:417 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.createConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:844)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:418 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getDBDictionaryInstance(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:602)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:418 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.endConfiguration(MappingRepository.java:1518)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:418 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:531)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:418 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:456)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:418 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.PluginValue.instantiate(PluginValue.java:121)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:418 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.conf.MetaDataRepositoryValue.instantiate(MetaDataRepositoryValue.java:68)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:418 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ObjectValue.instantiate(ObjectValue.java:83)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:418 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.newMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:949)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:419 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.getMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:940)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:419 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.initialize(BrokerImpl.java:335)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:419 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.persistence.kernel.WsJpaBrokerImpl.initialize(WsJpaBrokerImpl.java:306)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:419 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.initialize(BrokerImpl.java:323)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:419 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.persistence.kernel.WsJpaBrokerImpl.initialize(WsJpaBrokerImpl.java:293)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:419 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.initializeBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:229)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:419 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:213)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:419 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:156)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:420 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:227)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:420 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:71)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:420 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:35)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:420 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAEMPool.getEntityManager(JPAEMPool.java:140)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:420 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPATxEntityManager.getEMInvocationInfo(JPATxEntityManager.java:242)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:420 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPATxEntityManager.getEMInvocationInfo(JPATxEntityManager.java:174)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:420 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAEntityManager.persist(JPAEntityManager.java:143)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:420 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.security.ejbs.site.SiteManager.AddSite(SiteManager.java:78)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:421 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.security.ejbs.site.EJSLocal1SLSiteManager_b1fc2dbe.AddSite(EJSLocal1SLSiteManager_b1fc2dbe.java)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:421 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.spir.webbeans.SiteBean.addSite(SiteBean.java:52)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:421 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:421 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:421 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:421 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:421 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:268)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:421 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:421 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:83)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:421 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:88)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:422 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:100)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:422 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:422 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:973)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:422 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:275)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:422 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1285)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:422 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:711)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:422 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:34)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:422 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:172)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:423 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:119)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:423 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:423 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:423 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:423 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:423 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:423 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:423 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:423 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:424 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:424 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:424 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:424 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:424 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:424 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:277)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:424 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:425 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:425 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:425 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:425 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:425 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:425 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:425 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:425 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[3/17/14 13:09:34:425 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)
```

Comment: You'll also get this exception in WAS 8.0.0.8 if you access a data source via JNDI which is not set up properly. For example after  installing a fix pack you probably have to adjust ${DB2_JCC_DRIVER_PATH} in Environment -> WebSphere variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we found the problem. Accidentally somebody added JPA capability to EJB project and it interference with prime JPA project.